# OpenERP Payroll formula for PAYE tax

Tags: python, odoo

I need help to compile my payroll using the following python formula for OpenERP. Can someone please help me to write this properly for payroll please.

```
if categories.BASIC < 120:
    result = 0
elif categories.BASIC < 180:
    result = - categories.BASIC - 120 * 0.05
elif categories.BASIC < 264:
    result = - categories.BASIC - 180 * 0.1 + 3
elif categories.BASIC < 2136:
    result = - categories.BASIC - 264 * 0.175 + 11.4
else: categories.BASIC > 2400:
    result = - categories.BASIC - 2400 * 0.25 + 214.55
```

Kind Regards

Answer (score 0):

Don't for get to indent, python won't work without proper indentation.

```
if categories.BASIC < 120:
    result = 0
elif categories.BASIC < 180:
    result = categories.BASIC - 120 * 0.05
elif categories.BASIC < 264:
    result = categories.BASIC - 180 * 0.1 + 3
elif categories.BASIC < 2136:
    result = categories.BASIC - 264 * 0.175 + 11.4
elif categories.BASIC > 2400: #the else statement can't have a condition
    result = categories.BASIC - 2400 * 0.25 + 214.55
```

Comment: It doesn't require the minus before the categories. So I would put this formula into the Salary rules?

Comment: elif categories.BASIC < 2136:
    result = categories.BASIC - 264 * 0.175 + 11.4                                                                    Pls help this line is subtracting 11.4 instead of adding.

Comment: OK all done and it's all working now.  Here's the final answer>  Many thanks to Johnthexiii

Comment: if categories.BASIC < 120:
    result = 0
elif categories.BASIC < 180:
    result = - (categories.BASIC - 120) * 0.05
elif categories.BASIC < 264:
    result = - (categories.BASIC - 180) * 0.1 - 3
elif categories.BASIC < 2136:
    result = - (categories.BASIC - 264) * 0.175 - 11.40
elif categories.BASIC > 2400:
    result = - (categories.BASIC - 2400) * 0.25 - 214.55

Comment: @KofiOtchere, I'm happy you were able to figure out the solution =).